# Evaluating a convolution sum with a unit step function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution, symbolic-math

I want to perform some symbolic computation with the discrete-time unit step function, which I cannot seem to find a built-in definition of. I've tried `heaviside(n + 0.5)` and also `sym('piecewise([n < 0 , 0], [n >= 0, 1])')`. Here is some sample code:

```
syms n k
unitStep = @(n) subs(sym('piecewise([k < 0 , 0], [k >= 0, 1])'), n);

x1 = @(n) unitStep(n);
h1 = @(n) 2 .^ (-n) .* unitStep(n);

y1 = @(n) symsum(x1(k) .* h1(n - k), k, -inf, inf);

simplify(y1(n))
```

Which gives the output

```
piecewise([in(n, 'real'), symsum(piecewise([n < k, 0], [k <= n, 2^(k - n)]), k, 0, Inf)])
```

(Not at all helpful) I cannot seem to get satisfactory results whatever I do. Anyone have tips for evaluating symbolic sums with the unit step function in them? I do not want to use `heaviside(n)` because `heaviside(0)` evaluates to `0.5`.

Comment: Why is that not "helpful"? What sort of result do you expect?

Comment: Try `step=@(n) n>=0` or change `heaviside(0)` to `v` by doing `sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin', v)`. But I don't see why your current output is unsatisfactory, it's giving you the correct result as a piecewise function, what's wrong with that?

Comment: horchler David It's unsatisfactory because it still has a summation in it.

David, That didn't help. I still get expressions with sums in them.

Comment: See, for example, here for what it should look like: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscreteConvolve[UnitStep[m],+2^%28-m%29+UnitStep[m],+m,+n]

Comment: Since that link doesn't load fine, I shortened it: http://goo.gl/ZyjS9Z